# Disabled Textbox Font Colour

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking around for a solution to my question, and have been unable to find one, so I thought I would ask here.

I have a userform with multiple text boxes on it that are disabled so the user cannot edit them. And I've noticed excel changes the font colour of disabled textboxes to a light grey. So I have been trying to change the font colour back to black for easier readability but have been unable to do so. I have tried changing the ForeColor in the properties window to black, and I've tried doing it via code, e.g.

```
Controls("Textbox" & i).ForeColor = vbBlack
```

But the textboxes still remain a light grey colour. Is there any way to change this?

edit: I have also considered changing the textboxes to labels but this would require a lot of work, which is fine but I'm hoping to find another potential solution.

Comment: Have you tried `.BackColor`?

Comment: No... I'll try that now!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work!

Comment: Not sure if you can change the disabled font colour as its a default behaviour of window forms. There are few workarounds - one of which is in the answer below (Locked)

Comment: Thanks to @Nathan_Sav I figured it out. Just change the font colour first, then disable it. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I tested your idea but I wasn't able to change the colour with that workaround. As soon as you set `TextBox1.Enabled = False`, it disregards the `.ForeColor = vbRed` settings. But anyways, if it worked for you - perhaps you should also share your updated code.

Comment: @PankajJaju IYou're right I locked it! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.locked` property, like so

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    custom_lock Me.TextBox1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    custom_unlock Me.TextBox1

End Sub


Function custom_lock(tb As MSForms.TextBox)

tb.ForeColor = vbRed
tb.Locked = True

End Function

Function custom_unlock(tb As MSForms.TextBox)

tb.ForeColor = vbBlack
tb.Locked = False

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan! Your soIution gave me an idea that worked: just change the colour first, then disable it.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I meant lock it.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want even enter it - just put the Label in front of it with BackStyle = Transparent